# Check if column does not contain all strings in list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

In my application the user enters a set of IDs which are stored as a list of strings

`IDs=['SU09729', 'PU17459']`

I need to check if the IDs the user entered are valid IDs by checking if all the IDs are in my dataset df

```
 ID Number   |  Date
  SU09729    | 8/2021
  PU17459    | 8/2021
  GH87955    | 7/2021
  AS14536    | 6/2021
```

If the user entered an ID that is **not** found in df then I want tell the user it couldn't find all the IDs they entered. So basically

```
if IDs not in df["ID Number]:
    *do something*
```

(this will give an error unhashable type list)

I'm having trouble with the conditional. How can I check whether at least one element in a list of strings is not in df["ID Number"]? I tried

`if not df["ID Number"].isin(IDs).all()`

but `df["ID Number"].isin(IDs).all()` equates to False even when all the strings in IDs are in df

Comment: I think you want `if (~df["ID Number"].isin(IDs)).any()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
if set(IDs).difference(df['ID Number']):
    print('error')
    # handle error there is an invalid key
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over all ids:

```py
if sum([1 for idx in IDs if idx not in df["ID Number"]]):
    # do something
```